# Collectors to map java 8 Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have below code

```
@Embedabble
public class key {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Id
    private String Name;
    //getters setters
}

@Entity
public class Information {
    @EmbeddedId
    private Key key;
    //Getters and setters

}

public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private Information information;

    public inforamtionResponse service() {

        List<Information> infot = repo.getInformation();

    }

}
```

I want to store infot in map form such as id as key and name as value. using java 8 stream  how can I do that?

I tired using java8 stream but unable fetch object from object.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code. It's not clear what you mean by *[..]fetch object from object*. Add your code and explain your problem more clearly

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

using by `Collectors.toMap()`

```java
List<Information> infot = repo.getInformation();
Map<String, String> map = infot.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Information::getId, Information::getName));
```